# How to pipe input to urwid?

Tags: python, pty, tui, urwid

I'd like to make a program in Python that works a bit like fzf - you pipe input, manipulate it, and it's piped to something else.

I have tried making a program like this in Python using urwid. If I set up a fake input within the program, it works the way I want it to, but if I pipe input (`cat foo.txt | python myprog.py`) I get an error. How can I make this work?

In particular, I would like to be able to start the UI before closing stdin, the same as fzf.

---

To give a simple example of the issue I ran into, given this program:

```
import urwid

txt = urwid.Text("blah")
filler = urwid.Filler(txt)

def quitter(key):
    if key == "q":
        raise urwid.ExitMainLoop()

loop = urwid.MainLoop(filler, unhandled_input=quitter)
loop.run()
```

This command line:

```
ls | python script.py
```

Gives this error:

```
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found
```

It wasn't obvious to me why this would happen, but looking at [this issue](https://github.com/urwid/urwid/issues/423) for example, it does seem to be related to piping input.

Comment: Full-screen applications don't read from stdin, they read from the terminal directly. If you want to automate them, use `Expect`.

Comment: I've used `expect` before. I am not trying to automate input, the piped input in this case is more like an alternative to reading in a file of data to manipulate. I mentioned fzf because it works the same way. Like you say, full screen applications don't (usually?) read input from stdin, so I'm not sure why this error is occurring, but I couldn't find any examples of using urwid with piped input.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the way to do this is to create a `Screen` that uses the tty, rather than stdin, as input. This screen object must then be passed to the main loop. Example:

```
import urwid

txt = urwid.Text("blah")
filler = urwid.Filler(txt)

def quitter(key):
    if key == "q":
        raise urwid.ExitMainLoop()

tty_in = open('/dev/tty', 'r')
screen = urwid.raw_display.Screen(input=tty_in)
loop = urwid.MainLoop(filler, screen=screen, unhandled_input=quitter)
loop.run()
```

[This old mailing list post](https://www.mail-archive.com/urwid@lists.excess.org/msg00665.html) got me partway there.